# JavaScript Case sensitive value find in select attribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello all I have drop down list where I am binding it using server side code in asp.net as follows

```
if (ds1.Tables.Count > 0) {
  foreach (DataRow row in ds1.Tables[0].Rows) {
    if (row["EmpId"] != DBNull.Value) {
    ListItem item = new ListItem(row["EmpName"].ToString(), row["EmpId"].ToString());
    item.Attributes.Add("Duration", row["Duration"].ToString());
    EmpType.Items.Add(item);
   }
 }
}
```

I have a change method for the drop down in my JavaScript to select the duration which is working fine

```
function UpdateDuration() {
  if (document.frmMain.EmpType.selectedIndex > 0) {
   var dur = document.frmMain.EmpType.item(document.frmMain.EmpType.selectedIndex).Duration;
   document.frmMain.Duration.value = dur;
  }
}
```

But as per my requirement in some cases I will remove one of the option and adding it dynamically as follows which is working fine

```
$('#EmpType').append($('<option>', {
  value: 18,
  text: 'Part-Time',
  Duration:'60'
}));
```

But on change of `EmpType` I am calling the `UpdateDuration()` and showing the duration in one of the text boxes. But as for the dynamically added option the duration is showing in small letters it is unable to fetch the associated value. It is possible to get or add option with out case sensitive.

[image]

I can mimic the code to get the other if Duration undefined and get the other, but I would like to know if there is other approach instead of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, check for both `Duration` and `duration`

```
function UpdateDuration() {
  if (document.frmMain.EmpType.selectedIndex > 0) {
   var item = document.frmMain.EmpType.item(document.frmMain.EmpType.selectedIndex);
   var dur = item.Duration || item.duration;

   document.frmMain.Duration.value = dur;
  }
}
```

or to make it consistent always use lower case `duration`

```
item.Attributes.Add("duration", row["Duration"].ToString());
```

**Updated after comment**

> I though of this too but is there other in JavaScript upon adding
> option it is treating as small case

HTML attributes are case sensitive. Still if you want be case sensitive I have a work around using [setAttributeNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS) . Use below code to add attributes

```
$('#EmpType').append($('<option>', {
  value: 18,
  text: 'Part-Time' 
}));

$('#EmpType option:last').get(0).setAttributeNS(null, "Duration", "60");
```

You should see the attributes like this

[image]

**Example**

```js
$('#EmpType').append($('<option>', {
  value: 18,
  text: 'Part-Time',

}));

$('#EmpType option:last').get(0).setAttributeNS(null, "Duration", "60");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="EmpType">


</select>
```

Comment: I though of this too but is there other in JavaScript upon adding option it is treating as small case

Comment: @Developer Updated the answer, hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and let you know

Comment: What it will be in older version? I got this error `Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttributeNS'`

Comment: This works for me `$('#EmpType option:last').get(0).setAttribute("Duration", "60");`

Comment: @Developer Good to know `setAttribute` worked for you. `setAttributeNS` works only for new browsers.  Please see this browser compactablity [chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS#browser_compatibility)